# c# jagged multidimensional jagged array type name does not appear correct

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

When declaring a jagged, multidimensional, jagged, jagged array, and calling its `GetType()` method, the square brackets in the type's name does not match the type that I declared.  It appears that the square brackets are reversed.

Why?

Observe:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declare and allocate a jagged, jagged, multidimensional, jagged array 
        int[][][,][] x =  new int[10][][,][];

        // GetType outputs "Int32[][,][][]", why not "System.Int32[][][,][]" ? 
        Console.WriteLine(x.GetType().Name
            ); 

        //text copied from above does not equal the type, this is this False, why? 
        Console.WriteLine( typeof(System.Int32[][,][][]).Equals(typeof(int[][][,][]))
            );


        //Reversing jagged, multidimensional square brackets of x.GetType().Name results in True
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(System.Int32[][][,][]).Equals(typeof(int[][][,][]))
            );        
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the example:

> Int32[][,][][]
>
> False
>
> True

Why does `GetType().Name` not equal `System.Int32[][][,][]`?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the answer.

ECMA-334 section 19.1, Array Types.  C# is in reverse.